# How can I override a child element's style settings?

Tags: html, css, jqxgrid

I'm working with a javascript grid plugin (jqWidget's grid).  It allows me to apply a custom style to a cell when defining its columns:

```
{ "text": i, "width": 1, "cellclassname": "custom-column" }
```

This is useful to me because I am trying to reduce the width of the columns to exactly 1em.

```
.custom-column {
     width: 1em;
}
```

Unfortunately they included an extra `DIV` without an id or class in each cell:

```
<div role="gridcell" style="left: 725px; z-index: 1171; width:25px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item custom-column">
   <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align: left; margin-right: 2px; margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 4px;">M</div>
</div>
```

In the HTML above you can see my custom class `custom-column` but the inserted child `DIV` includes padding and margins which I believe is affecting the grid cell by making it much larger than `1em` (it appears closer to `3em`).

Is there anything I can add in my `custom-column` class that would override or counter the padding and margin settings in the child?

**Update : More info after change**

Based on comment and the first answer I changed my custom-class to look like this:

```
.custom-column > div {
   width: 1em;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell this made no difference.  I'm including a screenshot of Chrome's debugging tool which I hope shows enough information to help.

[image]

Comment: Did you already try  `.custom-column > div { }`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add this CSS rule:

```
.custom-column > div{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

If the `div` is not an immediate child, replace `>` with a blank space.

You will have to add the keyword `!important` after every rule because the styles are inside the div element.

Note:
But adding too much of this rule is not a good practice.

Comment: yes use `! important` the widget adds inline css to the `<div>'s` so you need to use a more important selector